# LINQ Transformation Function

Tags: c#, linq

Just one curious question from me, is there any transformation function in linq. I mean if i have `List<int>` or `List<Foo>`, i would like to change the elements at say index x or whoever satisfy the condition in Where.

Comment: Could you be more specific? With LINQ, you can filter, group, order, project, etc., your data into all new sequences of all new types. What specifically are you looking to do?

Comment: Your question title is roughly the definition of Projection Operator.

Comment: all the special chars have been lost in the original post :). anyways, i was thinking about transformation say add 2 to all the items of list of integer. or say transformed instances of foos in list of foos ..... @Jani, projection is not transformation i guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're looking to *conditionally* project a Foo to another Foo (leaving others untouched), you can do something like:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...

var transformed = foos.Select(foo => myCondition(foo) ? transform(foo) : foo);
```

On the other hand, if you only want to project Foos that match the condition:

```
var transformed = foos.Where(foo => myCondition(foo))
                      .Select(foo => transform(foo));
```

Do note that both of these return *new* sequences - LINQ isn't normally used to *modify* existing collections. You could of course materialize the results into a collection, overwriting an existing variable if necessary.

```
// assuming the transform is from Foo -> Foo
foos = foos.Select(foo => transform(foo)).ToList();
```

Since you specifically mention *lists*, there is another non-LINQ immediate-execution alternative to the first query - the [**`List<T>.ConvertAll`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...

// implicitly List<Foo> assuming the transform is from Foo -> Foo
var transformed = foos.ConvertAll
                  (foo => myCondition(foo) ? transform(foo) : foo);
```

---

**EDIT**: Sounds like you're looking for a "ReplaceWhere" method - as far as I know, there is no *direct* framework method that replaces the elements of a list based on a predicate. It's easy to write one yourself though:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces items in a list that match the specified predicate,
/// based on the specified selector. 
/// </summary>
public static void ReplaceWhere<T>(this IList<T> list,
                                   Func<T, bool> predicate,
                                   Func<T, T> selector)
{
    // null-checks here.

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        T item = list[i];

        if (predicate(item))
            list[i] = selector(item);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
List<int> myList = ...
myList.ReplaceWhere(i => i > 0, i => i * i);
```

Comment: i am aware of the projection, but again this is only projection not transformation which will change the element in the original list.

Comment: @Mubashir Khan: Does my edit do what you want? If you don't care about the predicate, pass in `foo => true`, or use a `TransformAll` method like from Gabe's answer.

Comment: +1 a `ReplaceWhere` extension has always managed to find its way into every project I work on.

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly write a transformation function:

```
// allows you to transform every element
public static List<T> TransformAll<T>(this List<T> list,
                                      Func<T, T> converter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = converter(list[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

// allows you to transform every element based on its index
public static List<T> TransformAll<T>(this List<T> list,
                                      Func<T, int, T> converter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = converter(list[i], i);
    }
    return list;
}

// allows you to transform chosen elements
public static List<T> TransformWhere<T>(this List<T> list,
                                        Func<T, bool> predicate,
                                        Func<T, T> converter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        T item = list[i];
        if (predicate(item))
            list[i] = converter(item);
    }
    return list;
}

// allows you to transform chosen elements based on its index
public static List<T> TransformWhere<T>(this List<T> list,
                                        Func<T, int, bool> predicate,
                                        Func<T, int, T> converter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        T item = list[i];
        if (predicate(item, i))
            list[i] = converter(item, i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that I made all my functions return the passed-in list so that you can use them fluently, like `list.TransformAll(x => x + 2).Sum()`.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, maybe `Update` is better than `Transform` because it's unambiguous that the data is being changed in-place.